# Searching for fields that don't match a regex in MongoMapper

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

In MongoMapper I can use the following query to search for items based on regex match:

```
Foo.where(:name => /Foo.*/)
```

How can I search for items that their `name` field do not match `/Foo.*/`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`$not`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-Metaoperator%3A%7B%7B%24not%7D%7D)

```
db.customers.find( { name : { $not : /acme.*corp/i } } );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in python (pymongo), this won't work, you get a confusing error about how you should use BSON regex.

However, it will accept python regex objects directly:

```
db['collection'].find({'name': {'$not': re.compile("^__TEST")}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this in mongomapper also works to search for the case where an email domain is not found in the email field, and approved if false:

```
non_org_email_users = org.users.where(
  :email => { '$not' => /@#{org.official_email}/i }, 
  approved: false).all
```